# How to fix tzdb.dat not found error in java?

Tags: java, sqlite, gradle

When I try to connect my gradle project with sqlite database, I have an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: 

    java.io.FileNotFoundException: null\lib\tzdb.dat (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile$1.run(ZoneInfoFile.java:261)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.<clinit>(ZoneInfoFile.java:251)
        at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getTimeZone(ZoneInfo.java:589)
        at java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.java:560)
        at java.util.TimeZone.setDefaultZone(TimeZone.java:666)
        at java.util.TimeZone.getDefaultRef(TimeZone.java:636)
        at java.util.TimeZone.getDefault(TimeZone.java:625)
        at org.sqlite.date.FormatCache.getInstance(FormatCache.java:74)
        at org.sqlite.date.FastDateFormat.getInstance(FastDateFormat.java:129)
        at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:70)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:25)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:24)
        at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
        at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
        at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
        at repository.JdbcUtils.getNewConnection(JdbcUtils.java:39)
        at repository.JdbcUtils.getConnection(JdbcUtils.java:52)
        at repository.RepositoryLog.findOne(RepositoryLog.java:28)
        at Main.main(Main.java:28)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: null\lib\tzdb.dat (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile$1.run(ZoneInfoFile.java:255)
        ... 21 more
```

I've tried to debug it but it says that it is a timezone problem and I don't know why this issue appears. I thought that this could be a a problem because of Java10, so I also installed Java1.8 but it didn't work.

```
        private Connection getNewConnection()
           {

    //I use the driver and the url from a bd.config file and it is saved in my //variables corectly

               String driver= jdbcProps.getProperty("jdbc.driver");
               String url=jdbcProps.getProperty("jdbc.url");
               String user=jdbcProps.getProperty("jdbc.user");
               String pass=jdbcProps.getProperty("jdbc.pass");


               Connection con=null;
               try{
                   Class.forName(driver);
             //this is where my error appears
                   con= DriverManager.getConnection(url);
               } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (SQLException e) {
                   System.out.println("Error getting connection "+e);
                //e.printStackTrace();
               }
               return con;
           }
```

I expect only to connect to my database and work with the database corectly

Comment: The null\lib\tzdb.dat implies you probably don't have JAVA_HOME set in your environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your  **C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202\lib** directory search for tzdb.dat file and copy it from here and paste in **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\lib** directory
hope it will work

Answer (score 4):

I Just had this problem and could only find this Question when I Googled it.

I eventually fixed it by following a hint on an Mboard (apache-sling@nabble.com)
They mentioned doing:
`System.setProperties(null);` somewhere, This has the effect of deleting all System variables.

When using a `Properties p = new Properties();` You have a blank set of System variables. Therefore doing `System.setProperties(p);` has the same effect as above.

If you want to add a new variable then you should first get the Properties with

`Properties p = System.getProperties();`

Then add your new ones:

`p.setProperty("MyProperty", "MyValue");`

and then write it back with the set method.

I hope this helps someone in the Future.

Comment: This was indeed my problem. I tried to load new Properties into my System properties like this:
Properties p = new Properties();
// load all kinds of properties with p.load()
System.setProperties(p);

All default system properties are gone now. When I changed line 1 into this it worked:
Properties p = System.getProperties();